# Oddly Specific Style - 70s children's book covers

Tags: style-identification

I'm trying to find if there is a name of an art style that I associate with countless book covers from the 60s/70s, mostly for books about the outdoors or the frontier. I've provided some examples that I could find but it's difficult since these books have been repressed with so many different covers over the years.

The "Ralph Stanley" one is an album cover and is the exact style I'm looking for. The others are close and fit that general style, but I'm mostly focused on the album cover.

[image]
[Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Hz1.jpg)

[image]
[Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTGQs.jpg)

[image]
[Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWpFc.jpg)

[image]
[Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMOYI.jpg)

[image]
[Click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9snP.jpg)

Comment: Hi The Leaberator. I took the liberty of editing your question a bit to make the title more specific and help with the lay-out of the images. If you disagree, or you see something else you want to change, you can always [edit] your own question.  If you want to know more on how everything functions, we have a [tour] and [help] that might be of interest. Enjoy the site!

Comment: I recognize this, but believe it has more to do with a certain painting technique followed by a certain way of reproducing it than a *style* as such.